Computing Bayesian model averaged posteriors
The Bayesian model averaged posterior predictive distribution for new data $\tilde{y}$ given training data $y$, across a set of $M$ models $\mathcal{D} = \{D_{1}, ..., D_{M}\}$, is defined as:
\begin{equation}
\tag{BMA posterior}
p(\tilde{y} \mid y) = \sum_{m=1}^{M} \int_{\theta} p(\tilde{y} \mid \theta_m, D_{m}) p(\theta_{m} \mid D_{m}, y) p(D_{m} \mid y) d \theta_{m} 
\end{equation}
The first part of the integral above, conditional on model $D_m$, is usually approximated from $S$ MCMC draws as:
\begin{equation}
p(\tilde{y} \mid y, D_m) \approx \frac{1}{S} \sum_{s=1}^{S} p(\tilde{y} \mid \theta_{m}^{s}, D_{m})
\end{equation}
where $\theta_{m}^{s}$ is the $s$th sample from the posterior distribution of model $D_m$, $p(\theta_m \mid y, D_m)$.
When it comes to computing the model-averaged posterior across draws, is it correct to say that we take the expectation of $p(\tilde{y} \mid y, D_m)$, and then weight those single values using the full posteriors of $p(D_{m} \mid y)$? Or is equation one above indicating that we take the mean of the weights too?
A simple example:
S = 100
M = 3
softmax = function(x) exp(x) / sum(exp(x))

posterior_predictive = matrix(c(rnorm(S), rnorm(S), rnorm(S)), nrow=S, ncol=M)
weights = matrix(
    sapply(1:S, function(i) softmax(sample(M))), 
    nrow=S, 
    ncol=M, 
    byrow=T
)

# p(y_tilde | y, D_m)
p_y_tilde_m = apply(posterior_predictive, 2, mean)
p_y_tilde = p_y_tilde_m %*% t(weights)

Unfortunately, this seems to produce a distribution that does not look right. If I, however, plot
posterior_predictive %*% t(weights)

directly, or even
# sample categorical model indices
m = apply(weights, 1, function(p) sample(1:M, 1, prob=p))
plot(density(posterior_predictive[,m]))

then the result is more what I'd expect.
I think I know what to do in practice, but the math from the equations above doesn't follow quite so clearly as to when to take the expectations over the marginals.
Can anyone clarify?

What you've defined as "BMA posterior" looks more like a posterior predictive.

@Durden It is the weighted average of posterior predictive distributions from each model $D_m$ in $\mathcal{D}$.

Indeed, your Monte Carlo approximation must be weighted by $p(D_m|y)$, since$$\sum_{m=1}^{M} \int_{\theta} p(\tilde{y} \mid \theta_m, D_{m}) p(\theta_{m} \mid D_{m}, y) p(D_{m} \mid y)\text d \theta_{m}\=\sum_{m=1}^{M} p(D_{m} \mid y) \int_{\theta} p(\tilde{y} \mid \theta_m, D_{m}) p(\theta_{m} \mid D_{m}, y)\text d \theta_{m}\\approx\sum_{m=1}^{M} p(D_{m} \mid y)  \frac{1}{S} \sum_{s=1}^{S} p(\tilde{y} \mid \theta_{m}^{s}, D_{m})$$

Thanks @Xi'an (like your blog by the way!). I think what's tripping me up is that, in traditional BMA formulated as a mixture model, $D_m$ is a parameter in the model, i.e. $D_m \sim Categorical(w)$, $w \sim Dirichlet()$, for instance. We then get the posterior $p(D_m | y)$. Shouldn't my first expression above be, then, $\sum_{m=1)^{M} \int \int p(\tilde{y} \mid \theta_{m}, D_{m}) p(\theta_{m} \mid D_{m}, y) p(D_{m} \mid y) d \theta_{m} d D_{m}$? I.e. we integrate over parameters $\theta_m$ and the parameter $D_m$?

Sorry, that last phrase is supposed to be: $\sum_{m=1}^{M} \int \int p(\tilde{y} \mid \theta_{m}, D_{m}) p(\theta_{m} \mid D_{m}, y) p(D_{m} \mid y) d \theta_{m} d D_{m}$

There is no integration over $D_m$ since this is a parameter taking a finite number of values, this is why the summation is used.
